# Azure Functions not be overwritten by new content published from VS?

Tags: c#, xml, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with an HTTP Trigger that receives an automated HTTP message, logs the message to Blob storage, and then returns a simple XML SOAP envelope response that acknowledges receipt of the HTTP message. Here is the code. The commented out code is other ways I've tried to get this to work but which was also unsuccessful.

When I test this code locally it works properly and returns the XML response. However, when I publish it to Azure it simply returns "200" in the response body. In a previous iteration of this function I was returning that "200" string in the body so I wonder if I'm simply failing to publish to Azure properly. I have checked the Azure Activity Logs and see updates to my app that correspond to my publishing attempts.

I am running .Net 4.6.1 and .Net SDK 1.0.11

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace MyFunctionsApp
{
    public static class MyNotifications
    {
        [FunctionName("MyHttpTrigger")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyHttpTrigger(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
            [Blob("my-notifications", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer container,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("The MyHttpTrigger function was triggered.");
            var blobName = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")}-{CreateGuid()}";

            var blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            using (Stream stream = await req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {   
                await blockBlobReference.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            }

            // Tried using a StringBuilder to assemble my XML response in case there was an error with my formatting (double quotes etc...).
            StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            xmlBuilder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
            xmlBuilder.Append("<soapenv:Body>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("<ReceiveNotificationResponse xmlns=\"http://apps.myapp.net/services/subscribers\" />");
            xmlBuilder.Append("</soapenv:Body>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("</soapenv:Envelope>");


            // Tried writing the XML response inline.
            //var xmlResponse = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            //            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
            //            <soapenv:Body>
            //                <ReceiveNotificationResponse xmlns=""http://apps.MyAppName.net/services/subscribers"" />
            //            </soapenv:Body>
            //            </soapenv:Envelope>
            //        ";
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                //StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(xmlBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")

                // Tried reading the XML response from a .xml file
                // Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText("../../../../MyFunctionsApp/XmlResponseMessage.xml")),
            };

            // Set additional headers
            //response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
            //response.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "utf-8";
            //response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            return response;
        }

        private static Guid CreateGuid()
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            return guid;
        }
    }
}
```

Incorrect response from Azure [image: Incorrect response]
Expected response as returned when locally testing[image: Expected response]

P.S There are some inconsistencies with naming in this code since I removed some identifying information. Please ignore that.

EDIT: I resolved this issue but I still am not sure how to overcome it. The issue was, as expected, the code I was publishing was not overwriting the code on Azure. I deleted my app and re-published and it began working with the below code. I would place this as the answer however I'm not sure how to overcome this challenge without resorting to deleting my app everytime I need to make a change, which is obviously not recommended.

Comment: Best way of solving is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the html headers in the request with working and non working apps.

Comment: How you publish the code, directly from VS? If so have you set to delete existing files in publish profile?

Comment: Yes. I am publishing directly from VS17. I don't, however, see an option to delete existing files in my publish profile. Where can I locate that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have identified the problem is that files seem not to be overwritten after publish, try to set delete existing files in publish profile.

On publish panel, click `Manage Profile settings...` and then check `Remove additional files at destination`.

[image]

Note that it's a potential solution since I haven't met similar problems and even without `Remove additional files at destination`, the sample project you provide can be updated(i.e. from 200 to xml content) as expected on my side.

BTW, update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to latest(1.0.24 right now) in case we meet some problem due to outdated SDK.

Comment: Thanks. This looks to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try returning `ContentResult` instead? e.g.

```
StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

// ... build xml....

return new ContentResult
{
    Content = xmlBuilder.ToString(),
    ContentType = @"application/xml",
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
};
```

Comment: I had tried returning a ContentResult in the past; it had no effect. However, I resolved my question. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add media type like below in the return,

```
return new OkObjectResult(xmlDoc) { ContentTypes = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.MediaTypeCollection { @"application/xml" } };
```